# REST Query Language with Spring Data JPA Specifications

Tags: spring-boot

1)Have created CropMaster Entity

```
public class CropMaster extends AbstractDomain {

  @Id
  private Integer cropId;

  @NotNull
  @Column(name = "name")
  private String cropName;
  @NotNull
  private Integer companyId;
}
```

2)I have created UserSpecification which implements the Specification interface that  filter using specification.here is the code:

```
public class CropMasterSpecification implements Specification<CropMaster>
 {
    private SearchCriteria criteria;
    private Integer companyId;

public CropMasterSpecification(final SearchCriteria criteria,final Integer companyId) {
    super();
    this.criteria = criteria;
    this.companyId = companyId;
}


    public SearchCriteria getCriteria() {
    return criteria;
}
@Override
public Predicate toPredicate(Root<CropMaster> root, CriteriaQuery<?> criteriaQuery, CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder) {
    Predicate predicate = null;
    if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(">")) {
        predicate=criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(
                root.<String>get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());
     }
    else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase("<")) {
        predicate= criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(
                root.<String> get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue().toString());
    }
    else if(criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase("companyId")){
        if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
            predicate= criteriaBuilder.like(
                    root.<String>get(criteria.getKey()), "%" + criteria.getValue() + "%");
        } else {
            predicate= criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue());
        }
    }
    else if (criteria.getOperation().equalsIgnoreCase(":")) {
        if (root.get(criteria.getKey()).getJavaType() == String.class) {
            predicate= criteriaBuilder.like(
                    root.<String>get(criteria.getKey()), "%" + criteria.getValue() + "%");
        } else {
            predicate= criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(criteria.getKey()), criteria.getValue());
    }
    }

    return predicate;
}
```

}

have created Specification based on some simple constrains which we represent in the following SearchCriteria class:

```
public class SearchCriteria {
    private String key;
    private String operation;
    private Object value;
}
```

3)creating repository which extends the JpaSpecificationExecutor to get the new Specification API:

```
public interface CropMasterRepository extends JpaRepository<CropMaster,Integer>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<CropMaster> {}
```

4)implement a builder CropMasterSpecificationsBuilder to easily and fluently combine Specifications:

```
public class CropMasterSpecificationsBuilder {

    private final List<SearchCriteria> params;

    public CropMasterSpecificationsBuilder() {
        params = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public CropMasterSpecificationsBuilder with(String key, String operation, Object value) {
        params.add(new SearchCriteria(key, operation, value));
        return this;
    }

    public Specification<CropMaster> build() {
        if (params.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }

        List<Specification<CropMaster>> specs = new ArrayList<Specification<CropMaster>>();
        for (SearchCriteria param : params) {
            specs.add(new CropMasterSpecification(param));
        }

        Specification<CropMaster> result = specs.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < specs.size(); i++) {
            result = Specifications.where(result).and(specs.get(i));
        }
        return result;
    }
    public final CropMasterSpecificationsBuilder with(SearchCriteria criteria) {
        params.add(criteria);
        return this;
    }
}
```

5) set up the REST API by creating a cropMasterService with a simple search operation:

```
 public Page<CropMasterDTO> getCropMasters(Integer companyId, Pageable pageable,LocalDateTime lastModifiedDateTime, Integer langaugeIdForUser,String search)
 {
   Page<CropMaster> cropMasters = null;
   CropMasterSpecificationsBuilder builder = new CropMasterSpecificationsBuilder();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\w+?)(:|<|>)(\\w+?),");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(search + ",");
       while (matcher.find()) {
        builder.with(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3));
            }
            Specification<CropMaster> spec = builder.build();
                cropMasters=cropMasterRepository.findAll(spec,pageable);

             }
            CropMasterDTOMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(CropMasterDTOMapper.class);
            List<CropMasterDTO> cropMasterDTOs = mapper.cropMasterToDTOs(cropMasters.getContent());
            return new PageImpl<>(cropMasterDTOs, pageable ,cropMasters.getTotalElements());

    }
```

Final response im getting:
  http://localhost:8080/cropMaster/list?search=cropName:Cucumber,scientificName:Cucumber

```
  {
            "cropId": 1,
            "cropName": "Cucumber",
            "companyId": 2,
        },
        {
           "cropId": 2,
            "cropName": "Cucumber"
            "companyId": 3,
     }
```

I Need to get for perticular companyid instead of getting for all companyid as i have mentioned below:

```
 {
                "cropId": 1,
                "cropName": "Cucumber",
                "companyId": 2,
            },
            {
               "cropId": 2,
                "cropName": "Cucumber"
                "companyId": 2,
         }
```

how can i get in custom query using specification.Can you please help me out.THANK YOU

Comment: I don't understand what you try to acheive?

Comment: When I look at 5) then I see the companyId in the method signature but this parameter is never used in the code.

Comment: I tried using this,cropMasters=cropMasterRepository.findAll(spec,pageable); where we will get list of all companies. but i need to get company specific .how can i achieve that.

Comment: Then please update your code

Comment: instead of using cropMasters=cropMasterRepository.findAll(spec,pageable);,i tried using this, cropMasters=cropMasterRepository.findAll(new CropMasterSpecification(companyId),pageable);.but,its not working fyn

Comment: But in CropMasterSpecification  you also don't use companyId!

Comment: so why do you think somehting should happen with it?

Comment: Can you post CropMaster source code